# Reading CSV using python to store in GCP Big query

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm new to Python and GCP , working on loading data from CSV using Python to Big Query.

Sample program is working fine using this documentation -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv

I'm getting data from other data base by creating CSV file , when I look at the data in Excel it looks good but in Textpad or notepad , if there are any extra spaces in the values like '  myname' instead of 'myname' it's reading as next row instead of single row ..by doing so it's give me extra row with less column..error - csv table references column position 1234 but line starting at position 12345 contains only 9 columns instead 10 columns..

Example :
Big Query Table :

Column A
Column B
Column C

CSV File Data:

Name,Test,Text
Name, Test2,Text - This link in Excel looks good ..going to 3 different columns but when I look at in Text pad it shows as Name," - This in 1 row
Test2,Text --This data in another row

1 split into 2 rows..how to avoid these while reading data from CSV using python .

Pls advice.

Thanks

Comment: Can you reformat your question to provide an understandable format of the input? I'm not sure of your problem here.